# radius of convergence of $e^x-2e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Let $A(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$.

Given that $\forall\ x\in[0,R):A(x)=e^x-2e^{-x}$, Prove that $R=\infty$ and find $A(\pi i)$.

**My attempt:**

$$A(x)=e^x-2e^{-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}-2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+2(-1)^{n+1})x^n}{n!}$$

now by using the  Cauchy–Hadamard theorem we can compute that $R=\infty$.

But I don't know how to find $A(\pi i)$, can I just assign the value to $A(x)$ without any explanation?

please help and correct my mistakes.

Comment: To compute $A(\pi i)$, use the formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ for $\theta\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: I know this identity but can I use it (since the function is Real)?

Comment: How do you know the function is real? what makes you say the function is real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power series $A(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+2(-1)^{n+1})z^n}{n!}$ converges for all $z \in \mathbb C$ !

From $e^{i \pi}=-1$ we get

$A(i \pi)=-1-2\frac{1}{-1}=1$.